# wiki: trouble setting up .htaccess for nice URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki

I am trying to configure a wikimedia installation. The wiki is installed in a subfolder of my server (www.mydomain.com/wiki) and is serverwise redirected to **wiki.mydomain.com** which was working fine.

I was able to use **wiki.mydomain.com/index.php?title=Main_Page** to access the site. But then I tried to use even shorter URLS like: **wiki.mydomain.com/Main_Page**.

So I created a .htaccess file **in the wiki subfolder** (which is accesed by wiki.mydomain.com) with the following content:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which also works for the sites!

**But**: The css sheets seem to be missing. - The sites look really ugly. 
How can I assure that only the page requests are redirected but not the file requests to the needed files?

Comment: **why** was my thank you removed? Why am I not allowed to be polite? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if requested filename is an existing file. If so, don't rewrite. Otherwise, forward it to index

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: cool! this is exactly what I was looking for! :) thanks for your help. i think i just haven't noticed the -f flag in the doc ;)